# PHP strtotime failure after 00:00 am

Tags: php

Why does `strtotime()` failure after 00:00 am? Example:

```
strtotime("24.09.")
```

works while

```
strtotime("25.09.")
```

does not.

Btw: These are Dates.
My whole script crashed after I got myself something to drink lol.

Comment: Are you sure either works? http://codepad.org/qVuXnqrH

Comment: In my exmaple i'm giving Dates.

Comment: @Jared, The first example only doesn't work because of this: http://codepad.org/249km0oo

Comment: @John - I know, I already upvoted your answer. `:)` Gamer, dates doesn't matter, it should work if it's a valid time.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to ask about time but then give a date. `24.09` and `25.09` would be `September 24th` and `September 25th`, respectively. If those were dates, time doesn't even enter the equation and your question is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

Even 24:00 working is a relatively new behavior. (As of PHP 5.3, according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).)

I would assume that the special case that was added to allow 24:00 to work simply extends to all 24:xx times, but no other, higher hours.

If you must work with strange time strings like these, you could do a little conversion and use "tomorrow 01:09" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is not a valid time. You can read about what values it will accept [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 0):

Because "24" is sometimes used instead of "00" to indicate the first hour of the day. 25 is never used.